# Custom ASP.NET Configuration Section

Tags: asp.net, configuration, web-config

I want to create a custom configuration section to handle email notifications. The configuration needs to be in the following format:

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="notifications">
        <section name="notification" type="NotificationConfiguration" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
...
<notifications>
    <notification name="..." enabled="..." delayInMinutes="...">
        <recipients>
            <add email="..." />
            <add email="..." />
            <add email="..." />
        </recipients>
    </notification>
    <notification name="..." enabled="..." delayInMinutes="...">
        <recipients>
            <add email="..." />
            <add email="..." />
            <add email="..." />
        </recipients>
    </notification>
</notifications>
...
```

I can get this to work fine using `NotificationConfiguration config = (NotificationConfiguration) ConfigurationManager.GetSection("notifications\notification")`, but this only caters for one `<notification>` element. How do I accomplish multiple elements to accommodate more than one notification?

The class that handles this is quite lengthy, so I won't paste it here, but it can be downloaded from here:

http://files.getdropbox.com/u/288235/NotificationConfiguration.cs

Thanks.

Comment: You can create a <NotificationsGroup /> outer element, and then put all your notification elements inside that group. This way, you'll be able to achieve what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ConfigurationElementCollection Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationelementcollection.aspx).

A reference of how to use it can be found on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CustomConfiguration.aspx).

EDIT: You can create a `<NotificationsGroup />` outer element, and then put all your notification elements inside that group. This way, you'll be able to achieve what you want to achieve.

EDIT 2:

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="NotificationsGroup">
        <section name="NotificationsGroup" type="NotificationGroupConfiguration" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<NotificationsGroup>
    <Notifications>
    </Notifications>
    ... Multiple notifications go here, instead of one.
    <Notifications>
    </Notifications>
</NotificationsGroup>
```

This means that `NotificationsGroup` will contain the element collection of Notifications.

Comment: Hi Kirtan

It is my understanding that ConfigurationElementCollection class is used for a collection of elements, not sections. I use that class for the <recipients> tag, but the <notification> tag is defined as a configuration section at the top of the web.config file, so how do I accomplish a collection of sections, as opposed to a collection of elements within a section?

Comment: At the top of the web.config, I define my custom configuration as follows:

<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="notifications">
        <section name="notification" type="NotificationConfiguration" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

Do you mean a group of notifications, as in my <notifications> tag?

Comment: Thanks for your help Kirtran. The tool below eventually helped a lot too!

http://www.codeplex.com/csd/